# Simple MySQL order by with varchar(64) does not work properly

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a table with a `varchar(64)` column with named 'value'. I want to select all the fields in the table sorted by this column.

It seems simple, but both my PHP code and `phpMyAdmin` are showing an incorrect ordering. I've tried changing the collation of the table and column, but nothing changes. I've tried renaming the column name, but nothing changes. Either MySQL is misbehaving at a basic level or I'm missing something.

[image: http://imgur.com/YIzgKCa]

Here is the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE  `Content_Data_String`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Content_Data_String` (
 `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `content_instance_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `field_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `value` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Edit: There must be something fishy with my MySQL install. The problem does not exist here: http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/#PMAURL-22:sql.php?db=Robin&table=Content_Data_String&server=2&target=&token=a29d3337e04a2be19aa92e83355b0519

Comment: Have you tried this directly in MySQL (workbench or commandline)

Comment: What is issue , what is misbehaving?

Comment: Note `value` is a reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: please post the result of `show create table \`Content_Data_String\``. Also, edit your question, don't screen-shot so we can replicate :)

Comment: @PratikCJoshi: As Robin has back-quoted value then there will be no problem because of that. Also - it is a key word not a reserved word denoted by (R) after the name.

Comment: Do you have the value column indexed - just thinking a possible corrupted index.

Comment: The problem is that the sorting isn't working correctly. See the 'value' column in the imgur link.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE  `Content_Data_String` :

CREATE TABLE `Content_Data_String` (
 `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `content_instance_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `field_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `value` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `value` (`value`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `value_2` (`value`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=236 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

Comment: I don't have direct SQL or command line access.

Comment: The column is indexed, I've tried unindexed as well.

Comment: How sure are you none of the values have leading whitespace or non-printing characters?

Comment: @Uueerdo, I'm very certain there are no leading space characters. I've created and re-created the table and data multiple times. The sorting is just not working and I can't figure out why.

Comment: @RobinBaker just making sure; you'd surprised how often that is the cause.

Comment: Should Collation affect the sorting. The database has a Collation of 'latin1_swedish_ci' (who know2 why). I've explicitly set the 'value' column as  'utf16_bin', it has no effect on the sorting, even after updating all the fields to make sure the new collation is used.

Comment: @Uueerdo, the suggestion is welcome. Often it's simple and overlooked things that cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys. My problem was that my PHP form was inserting spaces in front of the field values. @Uueerdo was actually right here. Even after checking his answer, I couldn't see these extra spaces through phpMyAdmin. When reconstructing the tables I was using phpMyAdmin instead of my php form to create the values. Thus the false positive that spurred my original answer.

Edit: Yep, one extra space in a template file. What a waste of time. Sorry again guys.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a table name with "order by".  Use a field name instead.  Example: "select * from Content_Data_String order by value;"

Answer (score -1):

I believe the problem is caused by having a column named 'value'. It is a reserved word, and even though I properly escape it's name in the query, the ordering is incorrect. This may be a bug in the version of MySql (5.6.23).

When recreating the table using the name 'data_value' I see that the problem goes away.

Thanks all for their help and suggestions.